# Home Page overlaps with other page even if we use exact with Using React Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to route to new component upload.js .I am using react  and exact for hiding other component in home page.When I click Upload.it shoud redirect to  UploadFileComponent component .what is happening is UploadFileComponent is loading and overlapping with all other component .added exact with  but its not working

```
//app.js

function Appp() {
     return (
         <div className="App">
                  <HeaderComponent></HeaderComponent>

                  <Router>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={HomeComponent}></Route>

                  </Router>
         </div>
        );
    }
```

//home.js(conatinerComponent)

```
class HomeComponet extends Component {

construct(props) { }
render() {
    return (

            <div className="App">                   

                <div className="container">
                    <div className="App-body">
                        <SideBarComponent></SideBarComponent>
                        <ArticleComponent></ArticleComponent>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <FooterComponent></FooterComponent>
            </div>
    )

  }
}
```

//header.js

```
class HeaderComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
           <Router>
            <div className="header">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="header-content">
                        <img src={logo} alt="logo"></img>
                        <div className="nav-links" >
                            <ul >
                                <li>Home</li>
                                <li>About</li>
                                <li>Services</li>
                                <li><NavLink activeClassName="active" to="/upload" >Upload</NavLink></li>
                                {/* <li><Link to="/upload">Upload</Link></li> */}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>                   

            </div>                
            <Route path="/upload" exact component={UploadFileComponent} /> 
        </Router>

            );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your links and all route should be in single `<Router></Router>`. Please don't use it multiple times.
Can you please try this...

```
   function Appp() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <HeaderComponent />
          <Route path="/" exact component={HeroImageComponent} />
          <div className="container">
            <div className="App-body">
              <Route exact path="/" component={SideBarComponent} />
              <Route path="/" exact component={ArticleComponent} />
              <Route path="/upload" exact component={UploadFileComponent} />
            </div>
          </div>
          <Route path="/" exact component={FooterComponent} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }

  class HeaderComponent extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div className="header">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="header-content">
              <img src={logo} alt="logo" />
              <div className="nav-links">
                <ul>
                  <li>Home</li>
                  <li>About</li>
                  <li>Services</li>
                  <li>
                    <Link to="/upload">Upload</Link>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/basic-components):

> The `<Switch>` is not required for grouping `<Route>s`, but it can be quite useful. A `<Switch>` will iterate over all of its children `<Route>` elements and only render the first one that matches the current location. This helps when multiple route’s paths match the same path-name, when animating transitions between routes, and in identifying when no routes match the current location (so that you can render a “404” component).

You need to add a `<switch>your routes here</switch>` to render exact one component.

**Note :: Also in your code snippet, you are using same `path` for all the routes. You need to change the `path` for each component otherwise for every path only first component will get render.**

**UPDATE**

Suppose you have more than 1 components to show on single route then create a container component and import all the other components to that container component like,

```
import React from 'react';
import HeroImageComponent from './HeroImageComponent';
import SideBarComponent from './SideBarComponent';
import ArticleComponent from './ArticleComponent';
import FooterComponent from './FooterComponent';

class ContainerComponent extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <HeroImageComponent />
                <SideBarComponent />
                <ArticleComponent />
                <FooterComponent />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ContainerComponent;
```

Then your route will be,

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
                 <HeaderComponent></HeaderComponent> //This can be added to HomeComponent

                 <Router>
                   <Route exact path="/" component={HomeComponent}></Route>
                   <Route path="/upload" exact component={UploadFileComponent} /> 
                 </Router>
        </div>
       );
   }
```

Your header component should be,

```
class HeaderComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <Router>
            <div className="header">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="header-content">
                        <img src={logo} alt="logo"></img>
                        <div className="nav-links" >
                            <ul >
                                <li>Home</li>
                                <li>About</li>
                                <li>Services</li>
                                <li><NavLink activeClassName="active" to="/upload" >Upload</NavLink></li>
                                {/* <li><Link to="/upload">Upload</Link></li> */}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>                   
            </div>  
          </Router> 
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: I want SidebarComponent,ArticleComponent,HeroImageComponent and FooterComponent must be shown for path="/".Hidden for path="/upload" .for hiding I have used exact in <Route> .It works (shows only UploadFileComponent) when I refresh the page with url "localhost:3000/upload".

Comment: @Karthi if you want to show all the components for a single path, then you need to create a container component where you need to import all the other component and use that container component in place of routing.

Comment: created a new component home.js and imported all the component .then, imported home.js like 
      <Router>
      <Route exact path="/" component={HomeComponent}></Route>
    </Router> in app.js file.but issue remains

Comment: @Karthi Check the updated answer and make sure you do the same.

Comment: I tried your code,it works fine if i refresh the page after routing .after refreshing the page ContainerComponent is not shown.If i don't refresh it  then containerComponent along with UploadFileComponent(the component showed up when path is '/upload' ) is shown.

Comment: @Karthi don't use router in `HeaderComponent` again, instead move your route from `HeaderComponent` to the component you added route for containerComponent.

Comment: I tried and returns  Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <NavLink> outside a <Router>.

Comment: Add the `<Router>` to `HeaderComponent`. See the code above.

Comment: Now it is not overlapping.but to see the result I have to refresh the page.

Comment: instead of `NavLink` can you use `Link` directly? If you can change `NavLink` -> `Link` then no need to use `<Router>`, you can remove it and it will solve your problem.

Comment: can you put your code into sandbox so that I can have a look?